# Cannot resolve PersianMaterialDateTimePicker

Tags: android, persian-calendar

When I tried to implement the `PersianMaterialDateTimePicker` in Android it showed me the **multidate class not found**.

I used below code,

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.mohamadamin:persianmaterialdatetimepicker:1.2.1'
}
```

How to can I solve this problem?

I checked this library and I don't found any things like `multidate.*`.

Comment: Would you please add the whole error or at least, adding a screenshot of where this happened? Also, use `implementation` instead of `compile`. [Check here](https://github.com/mohamad-amin/PersianMaterialDateTimePicker/wiki/Importing-to-Android-Studio)

Answer (score 0):

solved my problem by :

1- open **build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.mohamadamin:persianmaterialdatetimepicker:1.2.1'
}
```

2- add **jcenter()** to **settings.gradle**

```
 dependencyResolutionManagement {
        repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
            jcenter()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I added this `repositories` in my `allprojects`

```
  mavenCentral()
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://jitpack.io'
        }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        jcenter()
```

it solved my problem, Hope to Help you

Comment: The library isn't published to jitpack yet. However, it is available in [mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mohamadamin/persianmaterialdatetimepicker/1.2.1) & [bintray](https://bintray.com/mohamad-amin/maven/persianmaterialdatetimepicker).

Comment: Please help me. I Used method1 from "https://github.com/mohamad-amin/PersianMaterialDateTimePicker/wiki/Importing-to-Android-Studio" but MY problem isn't solved

Comment: @mehdi even by adding this repositories?

Comment: try deleting library, then clean and rebuild your project, after that add it again

Comment: mr  Milad Bahmanabadi thanks for your attention. i did that, but my problem not solved.

Comment: thanks guys for attentions. I solved my problem. I don't used implements like ondatelistner or ontimelistner.